# copying 2d matrix file into a 2d vector with unknown size

Tags: c++, vector

I have a file which is made up of unknown rows but 2 columns and I would like to read this to a 2d vector, but I cannot achieve it, as my code skips the first columns all the time, i dont know why

I have written the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
// this is for file handleing

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ifstream fp("test3_r.txt");

    std::string token;


    vector< vector<int> > vt1;


    int x = 0;

    char split_char = ' ';

    
    int i =0;

    std::vector<int> inner_vector;

    while (std::getline(fp, token,split_char))
    {
        inner_vector.push_back(stoi(token));
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            vt1.push_back(inner_vector);
            inner_vector.clear();
        }
        i++;
    

    }



    for (int i = 0; i < vt1.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vt1[i].size(); j++)
    {
        cout << vt1[i][j];
        cout << " ";

    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

    fp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

example of my input file:

```
0 3
0 7
0 10
0 16
0 23
0 25
0 26
0 28
0 30
1 17
1 18
2 18
2 25
3 0
3 10
3 11
3 16
3 19
3 25
3 28
3 31
4 10
4 18
4 25
5 0
5 9
5 10
5 11
5 16
5 18
5 23
5 25
5 28
6 0
6 1
6 4
6 9
6 10
6 11
6 12
6 15
6 16
6 18
6 23
6 25
6 27
6 28
6 30
7 0
7 18
7 22
7 23
7 25
```

The output i get is:

```
0 3 
7 10 
16 23 
25 26 
28 30 
17 18 
18 25 
0 10 
11 16 
19 25 
28 31 
10 18 
25 0 
9 10 
11 16 
18 23 
25 28 
0 1 
4 9 
10 11 
12 15 
16 18 
23 25 
27 28 
30 0 
18 22 
23 25
```

Which is not what i want. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```cpp
inner_vector.push_back(stoi(token));
```

What you thought you were doing was passing in things like "0" then "3", then "0" etc. But the thing is you were passing in things like "0", " 3\n0", " 7\n0". The getline ignores the endline and when passing in something like " 3\n0" into stoi it returns 3 and cuts off everything after the special character. My implementation is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fp("f.txt");

    string token;

    vector< vector<int> > vt1;

    while(getline(fp, token)){ // if you are given the size just do fp >> 
        vector<int> cols(2);
        stringstream ss(token);

        ss >> cols[0] >> cols[1];
        vt1.push_back(cols);
        cols.clear();
    }

    for (auto &i : vt1){
        cout << i[0] << ' ' << i[1] << endl;
    }

}
```

As far as I know you can't get getline to delimit more than one character so this is the next best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have overcomplicated your approach.

If your vector is only ever going to have 2 elements, using a `std::vector` to hold them is overkill.  You could easily use a `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, or implement your own class `Vector2D` to hold the components.  Using the latter would allow you to do something like the following:

```
std::vector<Vector2D> vt1;
vt1.assign(std::istream_iterator<Vector2D>(fp), std::istream_iterator<Vector2D>());
```

If there is some reason you must use a vector of vectors to hold your data, you can still accomplish it in an easier fashion:

```
int x, y;
while (fp >> x >> y)
{
    std::vector<int> t {x, y};
    vt1.push_back(t);
}
```

It is unnecessary to read in the line, and then try to parse the integers out of the lines.  The extraction operator already does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just so u know u dont need to use std:: when u have "using namespace std;", the whole point of using namespace is to avoid std::

Comment: if they were to have a more complicated project with multiple files and more functions it would make sense to not include `using namespace std` just to avoid confusion and name collisions. Here's a great [informational video](https://youtu.be/4NYC-VU-svE?t=145), timestamp at 2:25 to skip the intro